# Basis of a polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How can I form the basis of polynomials with degree atmost 4 and have root at x=2.Is it possible to have this basis such that no polynomial in it has degree equal to 2.
 I know $\lbrace 1,x,x^2,..\rbrace$ form the basis of monic polynomial, can the one with root 2 be like $\lbrace x^-4,x^3-8,x^4-16,...\rbrace$.

Comment: Polynomials can either be written as a sum (like $f(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots$) or as a product (like $f(x) = c(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\dots$).  Writing them as a product may be much easier here.

Comment: Do you want a basis for $\;\Bbb R_4[x]\;$ such that all the elements in it have  the root $\;x=2\;$ , or do you want a basis for the subspace of $\;\Bbb R_4[x]\;$ of all polynomials that vanish at $\;x=2\;$ ? You need to be clear when asking things in mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.The point is, suppose that your polynomial (call it $ax^4 +bx^4+cx^2+dx+e$) is divisible by $x-2$, then it can  be written in the form $(x-2)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$, where $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary real constants.

This furnishes a basis for your space: $\{ (x-2), x(x-2),x^2(x-2),x^3(x-2)\}$, using  the usual argument. Hence, your space has dimension four.

As for the second question, my answer would have been no, but for a magical intervention by @GerryMyerson above.

So, it's very simple. If your basis is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$, then you can very conveniently add up each of these elements, taking  $4$ at a time, $3$ at a time etc. So we would get a new basis $\{x^3,x^3+x^2,x^3+x^2+x,x^3+x^2+x+1 \}$.

To see why the above gives a basis, simply note that pairwise differences give you back all the powers of $x$: $1 = (x^3+x^2+x) - (x^3+x^2+x+1)$, $x = (x^3+x^2+x)-(x^3+x^2)$, $x^2=(x^3+x^2)-x^3$, and $x^3$ is already in the basis. So the usual basis elements are in the linear span, causing the whole space to be the linear span.

Now multiply each of these terms by $(x-2)$, and you get a new basis, namely:
$$
\{x^3(x-2),(x^3+x^2)(x-2),(x^3+x^2+x)(x-2),(x^3+x^2+x+1)(x-2)\}
$$

Comment: So, what happens if you replace your degree 2 basis element with the sum of the degree 2 and the degree 3?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, I see! So we could simply have a basis, by adding basis elements together and collating them. So for example, $\{1,x,x^2,x^3 \}$ gives another basis by simply considering $\{ 1+x+x^2+x^3, x+x^2+x^3,x^2+x^3,x^3\}$, so that removes the constraints I had initially thought would be conflicting with the freedom with which I could create polynomials. Oh, thank you for pointing this out, because I actually did not know this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much...really helpful

Comment: @FAIZ You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

See any polynomial with one root =2 can be represented by (x-2)f (x)= 
$ (x-2)(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3) $ where the coefficients are arbitrary.

Now as seen f is a polynomial of degree at most 3 and we know that f is isomorphic to $ R^4 $ .Henc the dimension is 4. And the basis can be found using the canonical basis of  f (x). $ (x-2) $, $ (x-2)x $  ,$ (x-2)x^2 $ ,  $ (x-2)x^3 $

Comment: But OP asked for a basis with no element of degree 2.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one where each element of the basis has degree 4: $(x-2)^4,(x-2)^3(x-3),(x-2)^2(x-3)(x-4),(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$.